# Scaling images when inputting a tex file

Tags: floats, scaling

I am using Xcircuit to produce images which creates an eps picture and has latex symbol which is overlays on top of it. I would like to be able to scale the image as well as the symbols. i tried the following code using the resize box but I got an error using code 1. I dont get this error if I just use code 2

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\begin{document}  
!  Code 1  
\begin{figure}  
    \resizebox{.9\linewidth}{!}{\input{myPic.tex}}  
\end{figure}      
! Code 2   
\begin{figure}  
     \input{myPic.tex}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}  


The code for myPic.tex:

% XCircuit output "C:/Users/CAPE/Desktop/Latex_Help/test.eps.tex" for LaTeX input from C:/Users/CAPE/Desktop/Latex_Help/test.eps
\def\putbox#1#2#3{\makebox[0in][l]{\makebox[#1][l]{}\raisebox{\baselineskip}[0in][0in]  {\raisebox{#2}[0in][0in]{#3}}}}  
\def\rightbox#1{\makebox[0in][r]{#1}}  
\def\centbox#1{\makebox[0in]{#1}}  
\def\topbox#1{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{#1}}  
\def\midbox#1{\raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0in][0in]{#1}}
\begin{flushleft}  
\epsfig{file=C:/Users/CAPE/Desktop/Latex_Help/test.eps}\\  
% translate x=384 y=96 scale 0.38  
\putbox{0.39in}{0.47in}{$\rho$}%  
\end{flushleft}
```

The error I get:

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{flushleft}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`! Don't use the `epsfig` package. It's outdated. Use `\includegraphics` from `graphicx` package instead.

Comment: You can't use `flushleft` directly in `\mbox`, so also not in `\resizebox`.

Comment: wow is xcircuit really still generating `\epsfig` ? hasn't it been updated in 20 years?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what you say is true, but in this case, it's generated code...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh yes, did forget that

Answer (score 3):

The (somewhat bizarre) TeX coding generated can not be used in a horizontal box (not to mention it uses `\epsfig` syntax that has been deprecated for 20 years).

However you can nest a `\parbox` to get something that should work:

```
  \resizebox{.9\linewidth}{!}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\input{myPic.tex}}}
```