# Scaling when \input PSTricks figure

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

I made a `PSTricks` figure to represent some `IPSec` behavior, but when `\include`-ing it, I have a scaling problem.

Here's what I produces. When compiling the separate file, everything is right, and all the frames have the same height.

[image: MWE output]

I try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226145/28926), but it didn't work.

Here's my MWE :

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=FR, per-mode=symbol, abbreviations]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=f](0, 0.75)(12.6, 5.2)

{\psset{framesep=10pt, cornersize=absolute,linecolor=black}
    {\psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray}
        \rput[c](5.49,4.5){\rnode{ipsec1}{\psframebox[framesep=5pt]
            {\parbox{2.37cm}{\centering IPv4 Header\vphantom{y}\\
            next : \textcolor{Cerulean}{\bfseries TCP}}}}}
    }
    {\psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Cerulean}
        \rput[c](7.6,4.5){\rnode{tcp1}{\psframebox{TCP\vphantom{ay}}}}
        \rput[c](9.32,4.5){\rnode{payload1}{\psframebox{Payload}}}
    }
    \ncbar[angle=-90, armA=0.5cm, linecolor=Cerulean,offsetA=.5cm]{->}{ipsec1}{tcp1}



    {\psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray}
        \rput[c](5.49,2){\rnode{ipsec2}{\psframebox[framesep=5pt]
            {\parbox{2.37cm}{\centering IPv4 Header\vphantom{y}\\
            next : \textcolor{BurntOrange}{\bfseries AH}}}}}
    }
    {\psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=BurntOrange}
        \rput[c](7.96,2){\rnode{ah2}{\psframebox[framesep=5pt]
            {\parbox{1.85cm}{\centering AH Header\vphantom{y}\\
            next : \textcolor{Cerulean}{\bfseries TCP}}}}}
    }
    {\psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Cerulean}
        \rput[c](9.8,2){\rnode{tcp2}{\psframebox{{TCP\vphantom{ay}}}}
        \rput[c](11.52,2){\rnode{payload2}{\psframebox{Payload}}}
    }
    \ncbar[angle=-90, armA=0.5cm, linecolor=BurntOrange,offsetA=.5cm]{->}{ipsec2}{ah2}
    \ncbar[angle=-90, armA=0.5cm, linecolor=Cerulean,offsetA=.5cm]{->}{ah2}{tcp2}


}

\rput[c](2,4.5){IPv4 Datagram}
\rput[c](2,2){AH Datagram}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

BTW I don't think my code is optimal, so feel free to improve it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the first example as a simple tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l | m{2cm} | l | l |}\cline{2-4}
IPv4 Datagram 
  & \cellcolor{black!15}IPv4 Header\strut\newline 
     next : \rnode{ipsec1}{\textcolor{Cerulean}{\bfseries TCP}}
  & \cellcolor{Cerulean}\rnode{tcp1}{TCP} \rule[-5mm]{0pt}{12mm}
  & \cellcolor{Cerulean}Payload\\\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}   
\ncbar[angle=-90,nodesepA=8pt,nodesepB=14pt,armA=0.5cm,
       linecolor=Cerulean,arrowscale=2]{->}{ipsec1}{tcp1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example can also be done with a tabular

and now the same without a tabular:

```
\documentclass[pstricks float]{standalone}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0, 0.75)(12.6, 5.2)
\psset{fillstyle=solid,dimen=inner}
\psframe[fillcolor=lightgray](4.25,4)(6.75,5)
\rput(5.5,4.5){\rnode{ipsec1}{%
        \shortstack{IPv4 Header\\
                    next : \textcolor{Cerulean}{\bfseries TCP}}}}
\psframe[fillcolor=Cerulean](6.75,4)(7.75,5)
\rput(7.25,4.5){\rnode{tcp1}{TCP}}
\psframe[fillcolor=Cerulean](7.75,4)(9.25,5)
\rput(8.5,4.5){\rnode{payload1}{Payload}}
\ncbar[angle=-90,armA=0.6cm,linecolor=Cerulean,
       nodesepA=6pt,nodesepB=10pt,fillstyle=none]{->}{ipsec1}{tcp1}
\rput[c](2,4.5){IPv4 Datagram}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a solution with the `\pspicture` I presented ? For my document I include them in, it's much easier...

Comment: see edited answer